# Активирование кнопки при заполнении DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

У меня есть объект DataGridView и кнопка перехода на следующий этап. Я хотела бы, чтобы эта кнопка активировалась только при условии, что все ячейки в DGV заполнены. Не совсем понимаю, в какую часть кода вставлять проверку на заполнение всех ячеек.

Код:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        bool nullCell = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value == null)
                {
                    nullCell = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!nullCell)
        {
            button3.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что значит все ячейки?

Comment: @NickProskuryakov все Cell, которые у меня есть. Я нашла метод CellValueChanged и теперь сложность именно в проверке на то, пустая ячейка или нет. Поправила вопрос свой

Comment: `button3.Enabled = !nullCell;`?

Comment: @tym32167 не работает :(

Comment: Что конкретно не работает? Поясните, что у вас на входе, что вы ждете на выходе, что пробовали и что конкретно не работает?

Comment: @tym32167 у меня DGV, у которого заполнен только первый столбик. Затем есть кнопка, которая по умолчанию дезактивирована. Я хочу проверить, заполнил ли пользователь все оставшиеся поля. Если да, то активировать кнопку. Выше код, который пробовала. Также вместо `j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count` пыталась писать `j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1`. В обоих случаях кнопка не активировалась

Comment: Пробовали дебажить? Вставляли мой код (`button3.Enabled = !nullCell;`) после ваших циклов?

Comment: @tym32167 с вашим кодом заработает кнопка только в случае, если я нажму Enter после заполнения всех ячеек. Очевидно, если я заполнила все ячейки, нажала Enter, а затем стерла одну из них, не нажимая Enter, кнопка все также будет активирована

Comment: Если вы стерли что то, не нажимая Enter - то вы ещё не применили изменения, то есть ячейка ещё в режиме редактирования и ещё не изменила своего значения

Comment: @tym32167 а возможно как-то это исправить, чтобы максимально избежать проблем? Сделать дополнительный тест при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: @Nataila рекомедую вам не давать пользователю заполнять напрямую DataGridView, а сделать форму с добалением данных.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov у меня и получается, своего рода, форма, потому что у меня первая колонка содержит ключи, которые надо пользователю перевести. Поэтому DGV один из самых практичных способов,как мне кажется

Comment: Для всякой проверки вводимых пользователем данных существует такая штука как [Валидация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-validating-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) рекомендую ознакомиться.

Comment: @Nataila покажите свою "форму", данные можете заблюрить